# How to find next (by a single parameter) element in c++? (stl)

Tags: c++, stl

I have n humans of THuman class

Each human has scored some points in one of two rounds. (score1 and score2)

Each human has its unique id. Score1 and 2 are also unique.

Besides, a human has a score_t=score1+score2, which can be the same for two of them.

I need to implement 6 variables  to THuman which return id of a human with:

1. bigger score1
2. smaller score1
3. bigger score2
4. smaller score2
5. bigger score_t
6. smaller score_t

(if there are many humans those satisfy theese conditions, the one with smallest difference of corresponding parameter should be chosen (like score1 for 1 and 2))

In other words, it's some kind of storing 3 human sortings.

Two more functions I need should get argument x, set score1 or score 2 to x, and then refresh some of the 6 variables above.

If I needed sorting by only one variable, I would simply create set and defined > and < operators for my class. But what is the solution for three of parameters? Is it possible to use STL here, or I should create my own lists/treaps?

__
Answer: [How to update set of pointers c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448058/how-to-update-set-of-pointers-c)

Comment: You can at least *try* (i.e. write some code) to do your homework before coming here ;-)

Comment: Just define an appropriate op<

Comment: just do some work and put the question....

Comment: You choose what to compare in the comparison operators, you don't need to limit yourself to one variable.

Comment: this is not a paid support site and you have not cracked up free access.

Comment: I don't have to sort humans by one criterion made of three variables. Or to sort them in three ways. I need a dynamic access to a human's neighbour in these sortings. std::sort() is nice, but if I use it in my update functions it will cost O(n*log2(n)) for each update. My first code built 3 lists on humans array sorted by unique camparasion function, but I realised that i don't know how to update my lists. My current solution is to build 3 classes, which of them contains < and > operators and a pointer to a human. And then to put them into three sets. I would be grateful for better suggestions

Answer (score 1):

[std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has overload which takes comparator as last argument, so you can implement any comparison.

You may be also interested in [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).